# Unable to import OpenCV in Mac

Tags: python, opencv, pip, homebrew

I can’t install `opencv` (or) `cv2` on my MacOS Sierra.

I've tried `pip install opencv` and it says:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv
```

And when I used `brew install opencv`, then it gave me a message that:

```
opencv2 is already installed but not linked so run this command:

    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

But even though its showing the same error and can't import `cv2`. Is there any way i could solve this? Or any IDE which will help me to import and use openCV?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

`pip install opencv-python`

After that you can import it as:

```
import opencv
```

Answer (score 0):

Add homebrew/science which is where OpenCV is located using:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
```

Install OpenCV

```
brew install opencv
```

That’s it. You can openCV at: 
cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/

Comment: You can use `brew install homebrew/science/opencv`; it’ll tap `homebrew/science` for you.